# how to extract part of audio in android

Tags: java, android, audio, copy

I'm playing an audio in my Android app, and I'd like to ask the user to set the starting and ending point and then copy the audio in-between to another file. How could I do this? So basically, if I have an audio file (in mp3 format currently, but maybe I'll need to convert it?), and two points of time, how can I copy that part of the audio in between to generate a new file in Android?

I'm kind of new to Android programming, so I'd really appreciate a relatively straightforward solution without using too many tools. Isn't there any classes or methods in Android itself to achieve something like this?

**update: found a solution. musicg could do it with easy-to-use functions. In the Wave class there are methods allowing you to trim a certain number of frames or seconds from the beginning or the end or both ends of the audio. But the input has to be 8k 16bit mono wav format.**